# C++ literal operator template not recognised

Tags: c++, literals

Why isn't the following literal operator template recognised?

```
template<char... Chars>
constexpr int operator"" _p(){
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int  fs1 = "123"_p;
}
```

*Update:*
Thanks to the answer I use now:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>

template<typename C, C... CC>
struct PgmString {
    static constexpr const char* str(){
        return &data[0];
    }
    static constexpr const char data[] PROGMEM = {CC..., '\0'};
};
template<typename C, C... CC>
constexpr const char PgmString<C, CC...>::data[] PROGMEM;

template<typename C, C... CC>
constexpr PgmString<C, CC...> operator"" _pgm(){
    return PgmString<C, CC...>();
}
```

This puts a string into flash on a AVR microcontroller. 
But if I increase the literal string length by one character the used flash memory size increases by two(!) bytes.

Answer (score 7):

gcc/clang has **extension** to allow:

```
template<typename Char, Char... Cs>
constexpr int operator"" _p(){
    return 0;
}
```

and then

```
int main()
{
    int  fs1 = "123"_p;
}
```

Comment: A sad thing is that MSVC still does not support the extension and [P0424](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0424r1.pdf) did not become a part of C++17.

Answer (score 5):

The form of literal you expect doesn't exist. Only integer and floating literals have template forms; string and character literals do not.